# Can't run android studio on emulator or physical device through USB tethering

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native-cli

[image: error]

I cant create a build of my react native app on android. The emulator from android studio crashes almost immediately and when I try USB tethering, it does not work either.

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\HP ElitBook 840 G2\Desktop\projj\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\HP ElitBook 840 G2\.gradle\caches\7.3.3\scripts\f3i9ecnk97bufb2cb7brpyj6m).
```

BUG/exception in phase `'semantic analysis'` in source unit `'_BuildScript_'` Unsupported class file major version-64.

I am receiving these errors when I try to build.